# How to get name of user account running a process on Windows command line?

Tags: windows, cmd

I parse the output of `wmic` to get pid (process identifier), command line, etc. of a running process. Unfortunately user name (user executing this process) is missing from `wmic` output.

Is there a method to get the name of the user account?

Example `wmic` command:

```
wmic process where caption="explorer.exe"
```

Output:

```
Caption       CommandLine              CreationClassName  CreationDate    ...
explorer.exe  C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE  Win32_Process      20180214220330. ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is using the command **TASKLIST**:

```
tasklist /V /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe"
```

Run in a command prompt window `tasklist /?` for help on this command which explains the used options.

The same command line for usage in a batch file with full qualified file name:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /V /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe"
```